# Some commands fail when active display/vt is different from where they are running, How to fix/workaround that?

Tags: linux, console, privileges

These applets are running on X at `DISPLAY=:0` (`fgconsole` 7).

**NetworkApplet**
Related to `nm-applet`/`NetworkManager` run this command `sleep 10;nmcli nm enable false;beep` (you must be connected to the internet, and it will be disconnected) AND fastly hit "Ctrl+Alt+F1" to go to vt1. It fails with:

> "** (process:1388670): WARNING **: Error enabling/disabling
>   networking: Not authorized to enable/disable networking"

**CpuFrequency**
Related to `indicator-cpufreq` run this command `sleep 10;cpufreq-selector -g powersave;beep` AND fastly hit "Ctrl+Alt+F1" to go to vt1
It will fail with this message

> "Error calling SetGovernor: Caller is not authorized"

**How to fix it?**
(if you know why this happens, I would like to know too)
(as a normal user we can issue these commands if on the right display, so I prefer an answer that does not require sudo, if possible)

PS.: 
`beep` requires `sudo modprobe pcspkr`
They fail also when run on another X (ex. `sudo -k X :1 & sleep 5;xterm -display :1`) with the same error messages.

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu trusty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have PolicyKit.

PolicyKit is a client-server system for controlling who is authorized to do what.  A trusted program, such as NetworkManager, asks PolicyKit through a Remote Procedure Call whether the user who invoked it is authorized to perform the action that xe has requested.

The rules for actions, processed by the authorization server, are in the `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions` directory.  Rules can state how they apply to all users, how they apply to users logged on to local virtual terminals that are not the active virtual terminal, and how they apply to users logged on to local virtual terminals that *are* the active virtual terminal.  All three can differ.

Clearly, the rules on your system say that these various privileged tasks can only be performed by users logged on to virtual terminals that are the active one.  So change the rules if you want that not to be the case.

### Further reading

- [`polkit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/polkit.8.html).  Ubuntu Trusty man pages.  8.  2010.  Canonical Ltd.

Comment: ah cool, so basically it is a security matter, not a bug, neither a problem! mmm.. I dont want to mess with polkit, it is cool. I think the right way is to have sudo privileges at sudoers to exec the proper commands without polkit changes. Thanks!